# how to add rows based upon checkbox checked and delete rows based on unchecked in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is code i have written to get checkbox value and add rows
can anyone have look on this and find what's the problem with this code

```js
$('.dm_list_data').on('change', function() {
    var $sel = $(this);
    val = $(this).val();
    $opts = $sel.children();
    prevUnselected = $sel.data('unselected');
    var currUnselected = $opts.not(':selected').map(function() {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    var currSelected = $('.dm_list_data').val();
    var post_data = {
        'deliver_id': currSelected
    }
    console.log(post_data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: base_url + 'curriculum/topicadd/get_deliver_method_details',
        data: post_data,
        datatype: "JSON",
        success: function(msg) {
            var JSONObject = JSON.parse(msg);
            JSONObject.forEach(function(element) {
                var delivery_mtd_name = element.delivery_mtd_name;
                var ftfl_hours = element.ftfl_hours;
                var assessment_hours = element.assessment_hours;
                var slt_hours = element.slt_hours;
                var markup = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + delivery_mtd_name + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + ftfl_hours + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + assessment_hours + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + slt_hours + "'></td></tr>";
                $("table tbody").append(markup);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Rows are getting multipe if i checked thrice please go through image
[image: image showing multiple row addedd when we clicked on two checkbox]

Answer (score 0):

Before you create a new element and append, just check whether it exists. If does not exist, then add it. Just add id for text box and if condition. Below code may have syntax error, i just tested in browser. Maybe little tweaks needed.

```js
$('.dm_list_data').on('change', function() {
  var $sel = $(this);
  val = $(this).val();
  $opts = $sel.children();
  prevUnselected = $sel.data('unselected');
  var currUnselected = $opts.not(':selected').map(function() {
    return this.value
  }).get();
  var currSelected = $('.dm_list_data').val();
  var post_data = {
    'deliver_id': currSelected
  }
  console.log(post_data);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + 'curriculum/topicadd/get_deliver_method_details',
    data: post_data,
    datatype: "JSON",
    success: function(msg) {
      var JSONObject = JSON.parse(msg);
      JSONObject.forEach(function(element) {
        var delivery_mtd_name = element.delivery_mtd_name;
        var ftfl_hours = element.ftfl_hours;
        var assessment_hours = element.assessment_hours;
        var slt_hours = element.slt_hours;
  if($('#'+delivery_mtd_name).length==0)///added this line
  {
//updated below line
        var markup = "<tr><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + delivery_mtd_name + "' id='" + delivery_mtd_name + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + ftfl_hours + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + assessment_hours + "'></td><td><input type='text' name='record' value='" + slt_hours + "'></td></tr>";
        $("table tbody").append(markup);
  }
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I have updated your code and posted above. Is it not visible?

Comment: I have updated var markup with id='" + delivery_mtd_name + "' on first text box and if($('#'+delivery_mtd_name).length==0) before var markup.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest create a hashmap which contains checked elements. Triggering Onchange will just update your hashmap and call a function to create/delete rows. hashmaps are way faster and easy to code.Make your keys as id of table row. Depending on check or uncheck condition, call function which is required.

Comment: I've implemented this in angular. For jquery I'll need to create a fiddle. Will revert you in some time.

Comment: please look forward for positive response,help me out

Comment: Hi can you provide your working fiddle? I will correct it in the sane way your using.

Comment: how to create fiddle i dont know,will you say steps for fiddel

Comment: search for jsfiddle or codepen. put your html css and jquery part over there (working one). Then I will look into it.